# Are there javascript issues with IIS?

Tags: javascript, video, iis-7, popup

I am in the process of moving a good number of websites from a Linux based server to a Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS7.   I am testing some sites we have to make sure everything will work when we make the big move.

I have run into an issue where, having moved everything from a real site to a test site, some of the javascript does not work anymore.  It is supposed to be a popup video player for youtube, and while it works for the most part, the part of the code that is supposed to make it a modal window that greys out the rest of the browser window and closes when a user clicks away from the video does not.  While the video should be centered, it is all the way on the left, and there is no way of closing it.  I have checked the script, and there isn't any problems with it as far as I can tell.  I even linked back to the working website's javascript files and is still does not work.

I can't be sure if it is a problem with a server setting, IIS setting, or some versioning I need to update, but it is driving me nuts and I can't move forward with the testing until I uncover the issue here.

If you would like to see the real and test sites, they are located [here](http://www.wrosslocklearlaw.com) and [here](http://www.budgetnationwebsite.com) respectively.  The video and most of the settings work fine, only a couple of them seem not to.  I take no credit for the video coding.  This is the only site I have used it on and likely will use it on in the near future.  I am more concerned about an underlying problem that could popup with other websites.  Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

Comment: No, Javascript is fully executed on the client side therefore server should not affect it in any way,

Comment: I confirm that the two sites appear differently, so your problem is not caused by caching or something like that. As Kristian Antonsen said, it is probably not javascript either, because javascript is a client-side thing. I notice some difference in the source code of the two pages, related to the scripts loaded by each page, I assume you are aware of it and you know that it is not the problem. (Or is it?) Have you tried launching the website from within a temp folder under the target domain instead of under the root of your own domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot more different between the two web sites than just the video. It seems that you have a .css problem. Make sure your .css file is loaded correctly.

Javascript cannot be the problem, as Kristian Antonsen pointed out.

Comment: Thank you Mike.  It turns out there was a missing css file.  I don't know how I missed that.  I am just glad that everything works.  On to the next set of tests I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is a client-side language, not a server-side language. Therefore, IIS is not responsible for executing it; the browser is.

This means that all IIS does is to serve the JavaScript (unless for some reason it's dynamically generated) as it would serve all other data. In fact, IIS is oblivious to the fact that JavaScript *can* be executed.

Therefore, IIS can't cause JavaScript issues.